# SOLVED - Ubuntu Studio 20.04 install EFI boot issue

Tags: dual-boot

I made a mistake. Windows 10 was not recognised when I tried to install so I googled and created an unallocated partition in windows

Then booted from USB went through install. Selected something else and created root, swap and boot partition. There was an error re some EFI issue may cause a problem. Because I read may and not will, I ignored this and now I boot straight into Linux. No menu option re Windows. Is this permanent damage or fixable? Hope you can help

Comment: No takers? Dissappointing

Answer (score 0):

Googled solution was to update Grub. Can close now.

Incidentally, I noticed some helpful editing, of my original post - just my sense of humour but I deliberately refer to a well known OS as "Windoze" with the last 4 letters, doze, emphasising slowness to the extent that I could fall asleep!